# How to cast (and Marshall) CityHash std::pair<uint64,uint64> from C# to C++ and vice versa

Tags: c#, c++, casting, marshalling

CityHash allows us to generate 128-bit hashes, but the 128-bit representation of an integer is defined as a pair of `uint64`s (as seen in the [header of CityHash.h](http://code.google.com/p/cityhash/source/browse/trunk/src/city.h)):

```
typedef boost::uint64_t uint64;
typedef std::pair<uint64, uint64> uint128;
```

I have a .NET wrapper that allows me to call the 64-bit version of city hash:

```
public ref class CityHashDotNet
{
public:
    inline static void CityHash64Batch(const char* const value, uint64* const hashes, const int numValues)
    {
        // I have a wrapper for CityHash that allows me to make batch calls (saves on interops)
        CityHashWrapper::CityHash64Batch(value, hashes, numValues);
    }
    //...
}
```

This allows me to easily generate hashes from C# by casting the value memory pointer to `sbyte*` and the hash memory pointer to `ulong*` and calling the `CityHashDotNet` wrapper function:

```
// The MemoryPointer is an IntPtr
CityHashDotNet.CityHash64Batch((sbyte*)values.MemoryPointer, (ulong*)hashes.MemoryPointer, size);
```

I would like to make a wrapper around the 128-bit version of city hash, but I don't know how to Marshall the `std::pair` that's necessary for the hash. I defined a class that matches the `std::pair` and I'm planning on using it to duplicate the `std::pair` structure:

```
public class Pair<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 First { get; set; }
    public T2 Second { get; set; }

    public Pair(T1 first, T2 second)
    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have no way to cast an `IntPtr` to an `std::pair<ulong,ulong>*` (`ulong` is the same as `uint64`). I tried casting it to `Pair<ulong,ulong>*`, but I get a build error:

```
// Does not work!
CityHashDotNet.CityHash128Batch((sbyte*)values.MemoryPointer, (Pair<ulong,ulong>*)hashes.MemoryPointer, size);
```

The error I get is:

```
error CS1503: ... cannot convert from `Pair<ulong,ulong>*` to `std.pair<unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64>*`
```

How do I get around this issue?

Comment: Trying to "save on p/invokes" doesn't make sense, you're not using p/invoke, but C++ interop.

Comment: Errr, sorry about that... I thought they're the same thing. I'll correct my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast between pointers to these types, they don't have compatible layout.  You'll have to copy the data between arrays of each type, one field at a time.  Do this inside the C++/CLI code, and let the C# code see nice .NET arrays.

Comment: I was afraid I was going to have to do that... :(

Comment: @Lirik: May I suggest a flat array of `uint64` (`array<System::UInt64>^`)?  You can pin it once, pass the pointer to the native code.  Then your batch wrapper can take-two-make-a-pair-and-call in a loop.